# How can I use previous location to redirect user in react router v6?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

```
React: 17.0.2
React Router: 6
```

Example: User are authenticated and try to access '/page2' through URL. They should fall through PrivateRoute flow and get to '/page2'.

Code:

```
const PublicRoutes = () => {
  const { auth } = useAuth()

  return auth ? <Navigate to={'/home'} replace /> : <Outlet />
}

const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const { auth } = useAuth()

  return auth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to={'/signin'} replace />
}

export const Router = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={
          <PublicLayout>
            <PublicRoutes />
          </PublicLayout>
        }>
          <Route path='/' element={<GetStarted />} />
          <Route path='/signin' element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route path='/signup' element={<SignUp />} />
        </Route>
        <Route element={
          <PrivateLayout>
            <PrivateRoutes />
          </PrivateLayout>
        }>
          <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
          <Route path='/page2' element={<Page2 />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

I've tried `const location = useLocation()` and use `location.pathname` but it gave some errors about multiple re-renders. Even the [auth guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth) from Router 6 didnt work because `location.state` is null.

Some info about my authenticante flow:

- Using backend as service [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) and only Google Auth at the moment.
- When user try to signin, it will redirect to Google Auth ([doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#web-version-9_4)) then back to signin page, my auth context will trigger and get their data and update app auth state then will redirect to '/home' if has auth

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `PrivateRoutes` component needs to capture the current location and send this in route state to the page you are redirecting to for authentication, `"/signin"` in this case.

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const { auth } = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation(); // <-- get current location being accessed

  return auth
    ? <Outlet />
    : (
      <Navigate
        to={'/signin'}
        state={{ from: location }} // <-- pass in route state
        replace
      />
    );
};
```

Now, somewhere on your `SignIn` component doing the authentication, access the passed `from` value from route state and redirect accordingly.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
const location = useLocation();

// Get redirect location or provide fallback
const from = location.state?.from || "/";

...

// in auth callback logic, once authenticated navigate (redirect) back 
// to the route originally being accessed.
navigate(from, { replace: true });
```

I notice also your auth wrappers don't seem to account for the edge case where the app doesn't yet know the authentication status of the user, and in this case you want to conditionally render null or perhaps some loading indicator until the `authContext` has resolved the `auth` state.

Examples:

```
const PublicRoutes = () => {
  const { auth } = useAuth();

  if (auth === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading spinner, etc...
  }

  return auth ? <Navigate to={'/home'} replace /> : <Outlet />
}
```

...

```
const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const { auth } = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation();

  if (auth === undefined) {
    return null; // or loading spinner, etc...
  }

  return auth
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to={'/signin'} state={{ from: location }} />;
};
```

Comment: FINALLY, I realised the reason why I couldn't pass state was because I had to write: `to="/login" state={{from: location.pathname}}` as opposed to `to={{
          pathname: "/login",
          state: { from: location.pathname }` . Your answer made me realise it

Comment: After a lot of research, this is the only answer that made clear to me how to implement the pattern of having a protected route with an automatic "redirect to where I really wanted to go" after login (if needed), with React Router V6.

Answer (score 2):

When using multiple pages, you can use `useNavigate` from `react-router-dom`.
The example below shows how you can call *useNavigate* on the main page,

```
let navigate = useNavigate()
navigate("/desired-page", {
    state : "information"
}
```

And in the next page, when using `useLocation`,

```
const received = useLocation().state
```

Which will fetch the state passed in the *navigate* method.

Comment: This work when redirecting inside the page but I'm still receiving state null when redirecting by typing through URL. I'm going to edit my question with more info about my auth flow.

Comment: I don't think I follow what your problem is. You mean by typing in the URL, it should carry information from one page to another?

Comment: Yes. Because my auth context flow works with Google Auth Firebase, once logged, it will continue be logged. When the user type the desired page, they will be redirected first to the default page with no auth state (signin) than my auth context will trigger that they already logged in, update auth state and redirect to default private route (home).